# BDD : How to use Mocha and Chai for implementing full BDD alongwith Webdriver scripts doing the automation?

Tags: cucumber, mocha.js, bdd, chai, webdriver-io

I have been using Cucumber for writing easy to understand Features , mapping them to implementation by Step definitions and calling using Junit Runner . 
This is BDD implementation I have been using till date.

Now , If I want to implement a similar situation where Features(Sceanarios) are written , Mapped to implementation using some mechanism , and called by a runner . 
How to do it with mocha , chai etc.

(I only know that Mocha is a testing framework and Chai provides assertion)

I would appreciate if someone can give some info or point towards a good source. I have already went through few tutorials but not found what I am searching for.

Comment: No joy? What did you finally decide on?

Comment: Still exploring mocha-cakes . Will update the thread once the option gets finalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [mocha-cakes](https://github.com/quangv/mocha-cakes) for BDD.  For chai, you may have to dig through the mocha-cakes code and see what assertion engine is used and proceed from there.

Comment: Also check out [cucumber for node.js and npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber).

Comment: I checked out mocha-cucumber on https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-cucumber . The thing that is different from cucumber-java is that implementation code for feature file is within the feature file in mocha-cucumber .  Please correct me if I am wrong .  But I would like a way in which we can keep them separate so that BAs have the feature file to work on and Testers work on the implementation.

Comment: @user3251882 mocha seems closer to native RSpec in its conception. I agree that separation of feature and step definition is better, for one thing it allows steps to be reused across features. I appreciate you letting me know what you find out.